# Looking For PHP Book Examples?

Tags: php, mysql

I just bought a used book which is the **PHP and MySQL Web Development (4th Edition)** but the cd was not included in it I just want the chapters example code specifically the include_fns.php since they don't tell you how to code in this file.

If any one knows where I can find the books source code examples please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Please visit [this link.](http://docs.huihoo.com/php/phpmysqlwd3e/start.html)
This is 3rd edition version. you can download book examples [here.](http://docs.huihoo.com/php/phpmysqlwd3e/Source/Source.zip)

**Edit :** I have just [Googled](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=PHP+and+MySQL+Web+Development++source+code+examples&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rlz=1R1GGGL_en&client=firefox-a) it and it was first link in the result. I dont know whether this web site supplies this material legally or not. You download and use this things all on your responsibility.

Comment: Thank you is 4th edition which is what I'm using but I will try this, again thanks.

Answer (score 2):

And [here](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0672329166) you can find source code for Chapters 2 and 3 missing from the CD-ROM

Answer (score 0):

The exact link is [Chap2and3SourceCode](http://www.informit.com/store/php-and-mysql-web-development-9780672329166?w_ptgrevartcl=Accessing%20Your%20MySQL%20Database%20from%20the%20Web%20with%20PHP_1248325)

It is update tab